# How do I run a Node.js process from Java?

Tags: java, node.js

I'd like to run "node index.js" from Java, but keep getting errors saying that "node" cannot be found (even though running `node` on cmd works fine).

Have tried:

```java
        String s;
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("node index.js");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("exit: " + p.exitValue());
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: How are you trying to run this from Java? I always thought that this was more of a JavaScript construct, and that it wasn't much used with java per se, but I could be wrong. Please tell *and show* the details of your code and your problem as per the [ask].

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels edited.

Comment: Have you checked the [similar questions on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+running+node.js+in+a+process+site:stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: Yes and I get errors like `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node example.js": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Answer (score 0):

If your code (above) is not working, one possible explanation is that the `node` command is not on the PATH *in the environment that your `java` process is using*.

If that is the problem, you could use the absolute path of the `node` command in the `exec` call.  Another solution would be to change the way that you are launching `java`; e.g. set the `PATH` variable appropriately in the script that is running `java`.